# Как найти настройки в IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, settings

Я хочу поставить себе настройку, нашел фото, где нарисовано куда нужно нажать, но я не могу найти у себя эту вкладку. Что я делаю не так? Первое изображение - пример, второе - мое

[image: вот картинка, что я хочу найти]

[image: Вот картинка как эти настройки выглядят у меня]

Comment: Это скриншот настроек старой версии (до 14-ой)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сверху над деревом настроек есть поле поиска. Вводите, например, "Synchronization" или "Save files automatically" и IDE отфильтрует дерево и подсветит нужные настройки.

Также согласно [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html), данный пункт можно найти в `File | Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System Settings`